# How to add Header to Avro Kafka Message

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, avro

We are using Avro Datum Reader and Datum Writer to build Kafka messages in Scala.

Code :

```
def AvroKafkaMessage(schemaPath : String, dataPath: String): Array[Byte] = 
{
  val schema = Source.fromFile(schemaPath).mkString
  val schemaObj = new Schema.Parser().parse(schema)
  val reader= new GenericDatumReader[GenericRecord](schemaObj)
  val dataFile = new File(dataPath)
  val dataFileReader = new DataFileReader[GenericRecord](dataFile, reader)  
  val datum = dataFileReader.next()
  val writer = new SpecificDatumWriter[GenericRecord](schemaObj) 
  val out = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
  val encoder : BinaryEncoder= EncoderFactory.get().binaryEncoder(out, null)
  writer.write(datum,encoder) 
  encoder.flush()
  out.close()
  out.toByteArray()
}
```

Since there would we multiple events per kafka topic, we need to add header to avro messages for unit testing.

How to add headers in avro file and produce kakfa messages ?

Answer (score 1):

Spark dataframes need their own column for Kafka headers. They must exist in a specific format of `Array[(String, Array[Byte])]`. Avro doesn't particularly matter;your shown function returns a byte array, so add that to a row/column of the dataframe you wish to write to Kafka.

If you have an existing Avro file you want to produce to Kafka, use Spark's existing from_avro function